# Reference for Excel Interop AddPicture2

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am trying to insert a picture into an excel file without compression and found a method `Shapes.AddPicture2()` suitable for this case
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addpicture2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Shapes_AddPicture2_System_String_Microsoft_Office_Core_MsoTriState_Microsoft_Office_Core_MsoTriState_System_Single_System_Single_System_Single_System_Single_Microsoft_Office_Core_MsoPictureCompress_
However, even after adding the reference to `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library` the method is not available. only `Shapes.AddPicture()` appears. Does anybody know, which additional reference or interop version I am missing?